# How to display labels outside the pie chart border?

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

[Pie Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ntxz.png)

I've used ng2-charts(chart.js) in angular. I need to have the labels outside the borders of pie chart like in the attached image. As of now I have disabled the lengend attribute. I'm setting the labels and background colors through `@Input()`. I could able place the labels above/below by modifying the `pieChartLegend` attribute but, I need them outside the borders. The position of borders will change dynamically based on input but the label outside the border will be static.

```js
public pieChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  legend: {
    display: false
  }
};

chartlabels: Label[] = [];
chartdata: SingleDataSet;

public chartType: ChartType = 'pie';
// public pieChartLegend = {display:true,position:'bottom'};
// public pieChartPlugins = [];

public chartcolors: Array<any> = [
  {
    backgroundColor: "",
    borderWidth: 1,
  }
];
```

```html
<canvas baseChart 
    [data]="chartdata" 
    [labels]="chartlabels" 
    [chartType]="chartType"
    [colors]="chartcolors"
    [options]="pieChartOptions">
</canvas>
```

Comment: I can advise disable chart.js labels and create custom one. (Some algorithm for rotating of div with your custom labels).

Comment: is there any plugins to do this?

Comment: I think no, but I hope there is not very dificult logic especially if you already have all percent from ng2-chart component's output. This is example of div rotating: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/product/ (see html and css code of this website)

Comment: Can you write an example with respect to pie chart? It will be more helpful.

Comment: Adding a div around pie chart and rotating it, will also rotate the pie chart inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the plugin '`chartjs-plugin-labels`'. There is a option to show the label outside of the pie section in this plugin. The calculation is done to show the label in the center of the pie section(outside the chart). I modified the calculation to show the label at the end of the pie section.

[Link for plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-labels)

Answer (score 1):

This plugin `chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels` worked for me.

Step 1: npm install it https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels.

Step 2: If using Angular framework import it in your components module like this `import chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels`.

Step 3: Customize as required https://piechart-outlabels.netlify.app/options

Comment: Can you go into more details on step #2? I tried to import into my module.ts but not sure what to import from there.